# No log out warning in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I have the SE Android app installed in my device (Jelly Bean 4.2). Well it's just a suggestion that while clicking the **log out** option from settings, we should be presented with a dialog to confirm that we want to log out.

Now what's happening is that if we click on log out, it directly logs us out and brings us to the home screen. This is a huge pain if we touch the log out by mistake.

Comment: Same for many other actions, e.g. deleting comments. Assuming you mean to ask "please add such a warning", changed to a feature request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for that and you are correct.There is supposed to be a warning for such actions.Most apps do have such basic features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature will be added in 1.0.84.